# How to send Numbers and Characters in one textField to Server?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one text field, in that text field I want to add numbers, characters like this (£ 12 /hr) and need to post to server but its taking either number or charecter I want to send both. if any suggestion it would be Appreciate.

Comment: in your code have you any code for textfield delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Get the textfield's text and encode it before sending to server.

```
NSString *post = textfield.text
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

`NSUTF8StringEncoding` encoding will encode into proper data. After that send it to server using `NSMutableURLRequest`